# The figure of speech in "with a flash of triumph in her eyes"?

Tags: figures-of-speech

Please, what is the figure of speech of the following expression?

> with a flash of triumph in her eyes

Comment: 'A flash in/of someone's eyes' means that a feeling of defiance, anger, proud triumph, or some other strong emotion gives rise to a short fixed and wider-eyed demeanour. The 'flash' is probably related to more white showing, and certainly the brief nature. Unless one posits a metaphorical broadening, or hyperbolic usage, of 'flash' (hardly at the lightning level), one might think no figure is used here.